# return multiple template literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to return multiple template literals?

Like this:

```
wrapperClass() {
  return 
    `masonry--${masonryData.direction}`,
    `masonry--${masonryData.theme}`
  };
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Thank you.

Comment: You get to return ONE value.  That value can be a string, an array, any type of object or any other primitive.  You cannot return two strings without putting them into an array or an object.

Comment: Need to follow key value pair structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to return multiple template literals?

No, not as two separate strings that aren't part of some other object.

You get to return ONE value. That value can be a string, an array, any type of object or any other primitive. You cannot return two strings without putting them into an array or an object.

Here are some of your options:

```
// return a two element array
wrapperClass() {
  return [
    `masonry--${masonryData.direction}`,
    `masonry--${masonryData.theme}`
  ];
}

// return an object with two properties
wrapperClass() {
  return {
    direction: `masonry--${masonryData.direction}`,
    theme: `masonry--${masonryData.theme}`
  };
}
```

With either of these options, you can call the function and then, from the return value, you can extract either of your two strings.

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you!